# Windows Phone 8 SDK Blog Announcement and XNA Confusion

Tags: xna, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

In the [Windows Phone 8 SDK announcement blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2012/10/30/introducing-windows-phone-sdk-8-0.aspx), I saw this:

> XNA Game Studio – Enables you to continue developing games for
>   existing Windows Phone 7.1 devices, along with desktop and Xbox 360.

However, targeting anything other than Windows Phone for XNA Profile will result in a Visual Studio 2012 error of "Windows/Xbox is not a supported platform for this version of XNA Game Studio."

So, am I reading the blog post incorrectly? Is it possible to target Windows and Xbox using the XNA Game Studio that comes packaged with the Windows 8 SDK as the blog post indicates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just got this response from Aaron Stebner (Microsoft Employee):

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/4a608bd0-e8a1-42ba-a1c9-d68f828604a7

> The blog post is incorrect.  The Windows Phone SDK 8.0 includes
>   support for building Windows Phone games that use the XNA Framework,
>   but it does not include support for building Windows or Xbox 360 games
>   that use the XNA Framework.
>
> If you are developing Windows games or Xbox 360 games that use the XNA
>   Framework, you must continue to use an edition of Visual Studio 2010
>   and either the Windows Phone SDK 7.1 or XNA Game Studio 4.0 Refresh. 
>   Both of those products can be installed side-by-side with the Windows
>   Phone SDK 8.0.
>
> Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I'm following. The Windows Phone SDK only comes with XNA for Windows Phone.

If you want to target Windows PC or Xbox, you'll have to download the full [Microsoft XNA Game Studio 4.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714) which contains the SDK for the remaining platforms.

Comment: The blog post specifically states that the Windows Phone 8 SDK includes XNA Game Studio "to continue developing games for existing Windows Phone 7.1 devices, along with desktop and Xbox 360." That clearly is not the case, hence my confusion.

Comment: The downloads and copy that link to them have always been a little askew, even if you do accidentally click on the right links.  Claus is right, just download more packages until it works.

Comment: I understand that the full XNA Game Studio is an option, but it requires side-by-side installation of Visual Studio 2010. I was hoping that the version of XNA Game Studio that came with the Windows Phone 8 SDK would shed that requirement in addition to allowing Desktop and Xbox applications.

Answer (score 0):

You have probably to install the full XNA Game Studio.
http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=23714
Also as the public WP8 SDK is now available, I can confirm that you cannot develop XNA apps for the WP8 platform directly. You can only target the WP7.1 platform with your XNA apps and they will run on WP8 devices just fine.